# Can't uninstall package filename too long

Tags: apt, 16.04, raspberrypi

For some package installations on my Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 16, I was seeing errors like:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libltdl.so.7.3.1 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libltdl.so.7 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsane.so.1.0.25 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libltdl.so is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcc1.so.0 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsane.so.1 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgusb.so.2.0.10 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcc1.so.0.0.0 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgusb.so.2 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.1.0 is not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 docutils-common
 pkg-config
```

So I tried purging the docutils-common and pkg-config packages. However, when I ran `sudo apt-get purge docutils-common pkg-config`, I get the error:

```
Removing docutils-common (0.12+dfsg-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/docutils-common.prerm: 1: /var/lib/dpkg/info/docutils-common.prerm: ������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������: File name too long
dpkg: error processing package docutils-common (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/docutils-common.postinst: 1: /var/lib/dpkg/info/docutils-common.postinst: ���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������: File name too long
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
```

What's causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Looks like `/var/lib/dpkg/info/docutils-common.postinst` or a file it refers to contains garbage. What's the output of `file /var/lib/dpkg/info/docutils-common.postinst`?